# Develop image contrast,sharpen,warmth,crop,undo,redo functionality in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, image, crop, undo, contrast

I want to develop image contrast,sharpen,warmth,crop,undo,redo functionality in my web application. Please tell me how can I develop this functionality ?  I dont want to use .GetPixel() and .SetPixel() because it is very slow metho. so please tell me any other way to develop these functionalities.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What have you tried? A simple Google search will return thousands of results.. over 50% of which are here on SO..

Answer (score 0):

If you need faster access to the pixel data on an image, use `Image.LockBits`. Note that any method containing this code must be marked `unsafe`.

```
BitmapData bitmapData = image.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
int* bitmapPtr = (int*)bitmapData.Scan0.ToPointer();

for (int pixelCount = 0; pixelCount <= image.Width * image.Height; pixelCount++)
{
    bitmapPtr[pixelCount] = ...;
    // etc
}

image.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
```